# Custom metabox field help tips popups

Tags: metabox, contextual-help, tooltip

Is there anything built-in to core that displays a little (?) icon next to admin-side input fields (custom metabox input fields, for example) that provide tooltips or a contextual help popup when rolled over? I thought I saw something like that once, but it may very well have been specific to a plugin.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you building out your meta boxes?

Comment: The usual way - adding the callback to the CPT declaration

Comment: Nothing I know of out of the box then. :) I love jQuery tools tooltips though. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/

Comment: That's a danged sweet library there. And completely license-free, I notice. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the jQuery UI is already built in to the WP admin and it is planned for the [WP 3.3 update](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17952) to include the rest of the UI.

It is not until [jQuery UI 1.9 final](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip) release where tooltips will be added in so perhaps after WP 3.3, jQuery UI 1.9 will be incorporated in thus adding in-built tooltips without having to enqueue anything.

Comment: Cool! We'll see how that works out...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without the use of a plugin, depending on how you display your meta fields you may only need to use some html and jquery for the tooltip.

My all time favourite for custom metaboxes is the [WPAlchemy Class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/). The file structure is very organised and separate files are used for different metaboxes.

For the tooltip itself there are plenty of jquery plugins available its a matter of including the scripts to display in the admin post section that can be accomplished using wp_enqueue_script.

More information on wp_enqueue_script can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, Matt. There are tons of ways one can roll one's own tooltips, but my question was probably misphrased, but really was intended to see whether there was anything out of the box that was designed for that.